# PHP: Can I split a JSONstring on it's first depth without have to re-encode?

Tags: php, json, behat, gherkin

As I'm not aware if behat can inject my Behat FeatureContext function parameters with anything but strings, I'd like to know if I could split strings in such a way that I am left with an array of json_objects.

I've managed to do this with `json_decode` and `json_encode`, but that feels a bit repetitive as I first decode the string of objects, 
only to encode it back into a single object.

Per example have the following Behat feature:

```
Feature: Provide a consistent standard JSON API endpoint

  In order to build interchangeable front ends
  As a JSON API developer
  I need to allow Create, Read, Update, and Delete functionality

  Background:
    Given there are Albums with the following details:
      """
      [{
        "artist":"Pink Floyd",
        "title":"The Dark Side of the Moon",
        "songs":[
          {"title":"Speak to Me", "length":254}
          {"title":"Breathe", "length":192}
          {"title":"On the Run", "length":188}
        ] 
      },
      {
        "artist":"AC/DC",
        "title":"Back to Black",
        "songs":[
          {"title":"Hells Bells", "length":205}
          {"title":"Shoot to Thrill", "length":302}
          {"title":"What Do You Do for Money Honey", "length":244}
        ] 
      }]    
      """
      And the "Content-Type" request header is "application/json"
```

and the following function in FeatureContext.php:

```
...

public function thereAreAlbumsWithTheFollowingDetails(string $jsonString) {
    $albums = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    foreach ($albums as $album) {
        $albumJson = json_encode($album);
        $this->apiContext->setRequestBody($albumJson);
        $this->apiContext->requestPath("/api/album", "POST");
    }
}

...
```

Comment: And why are you re-encoding it to JSON…?!

Comment: There;s nothing wrong with this code. It's readable and understandable.

Comment: And no, you basically need a JSON-parser to correctly split the string. What you're doing is the most practical approach.

Comment: If `doSomething()` took an array rather than JSON it would be easier.  But your `json_encode($albums)` looks wrong as it's encoding the original data and not each album.

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. Its main usage is to transfer the data across the network, store the data (in a database, in a file on the disk etc) or pass it to a different program (probably written in a different language). Apart from these purposes, handling data as JSON is, most probably, a misunderstanding of its goals.

Comment: Sorry about that. `json_encode($albums)` should be `json_encode($album)`.

Comment: As an alternative to passing JSON, how about creating a class for an Album, this can be populated and then passed around.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear why that's not an option.

Comment: @deceze So it's impossible?

Comment: Well, again, you will need something with at least a rudimentary understanding of the JSON format. Perhaps a streamable JSON parser would technically not require you to decode the JSON and just stream its parts… but the code will be more complex and performance-wise it'll only make a difference for *massive* JSON data. Sooooo… why bother?

Comment: Put that down as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following a tutorial that added the first test objects via REST, but that doesn't have to happen.

I have also learned that nested tables for Behat are a bad idea.

https://joebuschmann.com/specflow-nested-tables-a-bad-idea/

*behat.yml*

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - App\Features\Bootstrap\FeatureContext:
                    container: '@service_container'
                    entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
                - Imbo\BehatApiExtension\Context\ApiContext
    extensions:
        Imbo\BehatApiExtension:
            apiClient:
                base_uri: http://127.0.0.1:8000
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                bootstrap: config\behat\bootstrap.php
                class: App\Kernel
```

Code below is not exactly correct, but it's close enough.

*FeatureContext.php*

```
...

/**
     * @Given there are Albums with the following details:
     */
    public function thereAreAlbumsWithTheFollowingDetails(TableNode $table) {
        foreach ($table->getColumnsHash() as $row) {
            $album = new Album();
            $album->setTitle($row['title']);
            $album->setReleaseDate(new \DateTime($row['release_date']));
            array_push($this->entities, $album);
        }
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @Given albums with the following Songs:
     */
    public function albumsWithTheFollowingSongs(TableNode $table) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($table->getColumnsHash() as $row) {
            $song = new Song($row['title']);
            $this->entities[$i]->setSong($song);
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @When they are saved into the database
     */
    public function theyAreSavedIntoTheDatabase() {
        foreach ($this->entities as $entity) {
            $this->em->persist($entity);
        }
        $this->em->flush();
    }
...
```

Comment: Depends on the scenario, for complex situations it's better to avoid nested tables, for simple cases nested tables are fine as they save overhead, as always it's a matter of evaluating pros and cons for each case.

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you want to add some data to set up the scenario, in that case I would move away from json as that's an implementation detail:

```
Given there are Albums with the following details:
  | artist     | title                     | songs                            |
  | Pink Floyd | The Dark Side of the Moon | Speak to Me, Breathe, On the Run |
  | AC/DC      | Back to Black             | Hells Bells, Shoot to Thrill, What Do You Do for Money Honey |
...
```

Then on *FeatureContext* transform the data to json if you need that, but personally, if you've done it correctly, I would just inject the same service that should be used in */api/album* controller to create the Albums.

Comment: I've edited the question in order to make it clear that Songs **must** be seperate objects. I can't just add them as strings.

Comment: That doesn’t make any difference, just add whatever separator you want to the songs string and then transform to array using explode, then build the json needed by the endpoint using the array data.